# Print hindi letters on dashboard imported from sql

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am building a dashboard on R shiny with tables containing hindi words imported from mysql but on dashboard only question marks (???) are printed

I have windows machine and have local sql server

Comment: Hi @Aditya, Please Share more details with your code for better understandability

Comment: You might need to change the locale

Comment: By changing local also  it is still not working , My problem solved b instead of using sql to take input upload dataframe directly to R

Answer (score 0):

By changing local also it is still not working , My problem solved b instead of using sql to take input upload dataframe directly to R